# Bokeh: Displaying Images with Hovertool

Tags: python, bokeh

I'm emulating the Hovertool example [here](http://docs.bokeh.org/en/0.11.1/docs/user_guide/tools.html), where the hovertool displays images of snakes. My own data consists of names of people, and their profile pictures. I have a local directory of all profile pics, so whenever I get a list of names, `names_ls`, I have a method `get_profile_pics` which will search that directory* for the profile picture associated with the names on that list.

Note how, in the snakes example (code from the example reproduced below for convenience) the images `imgs` are stored in the ColumnDataSource `data` dictionary as html urls. I want to try to display images that are stored on my local drive instead, how could I go about doing that?

Some pointers:

1. Assume that I will always have a profile pic of whatever names I'm given. Many people can have the same name, but `get_profile_pics` takes care of that.
2. I'd like to run all this in a jupyter notebook.
3. The pics are .pngs, and I've also saved those profile pics as .npy files, if that helps.
4. Because of privacy issues, I don't want to host the images on the net to retrieve using a html tag.

**Snakes Hovertool example code**

```
source = ColumnDataSource(
        data=dict(
            x=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
            y=[2, 5, 8, 2, 7],
            desc=['A', 'b', 'C', 'd', 'E'],
            imgs = [
                'http://docs.bokeh.org/static/snake.jpg',
                'http://docs.bokeh.org/static/snake2.png',
                'http://docs.bokeh.org/static/snake3D.png',
                'http://docs.bokeh.org/static/snake4_TheRevenge.png',
                'http://docs.bokeh.org/static/snakebite.jpg'
            ]
        )
    )

hover = HoverTool(
        tooltips="""
        <div>
            <div>
                <img
                    src="@imgs" height="42" alt="@imgs" width="42"
                    style="float: left; margin: 0px 15px 15px 0px;"
                    border="2"
                ></img>
            </div>
        <...other div tags for text>
        """
    )
```

I've tried various formats: as PIL.Image images, as np.arrays, and as bytes. tldr: none of these work. My code, for completeness:

```
list_of_pics_PIL = [...]
list_of_pics_np = [...]
list_of_pics_png = [...]
type(list_of_pics_PIL[0]) #PIL.Image.Image
type(list_of_pics_np[0]) #numpy.ndarray
type(list_of_pics_png[0]) #bytes

selected_pics_PIL = get_profile_pics(names_ls, list_of_pics_PIL)
selected_pics_np = get_profile_pics(names_ls, list_of_pics_np)
selected_pics_png = get_profile_pics(names_ls, list_of_pics_png)

source = ColumnDataSource(
        data=dict(
            names = list_of_names,
            height = person_height,
            pics = selected_pics_<format>
            )
       )

hover = HoverTool(
        tooltips="""
        <div>
            <div>
                <img
                    src="@pics" height="42" alt="@imgs" width="42"
                    style="float: left; margin: 0px 15px 15px 0px;"
                    border="2"
                ></img>
            </div>
        <...other div tags for text>
        """
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

replace @pics with file://@pics and enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

To insert an image in a custom hovertool template, the image needs to be available at some public URL so that you can put in a standard HTML `<img>` tag in the template. It *might* if the images were base64-encoded data-urls in the CDS.